# Django Error: Reverse for 'update-qty' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['update\\-qty/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/$']

Tags: python, django

I am trying to fix a no reverse error but I am making something wrong I can't figure it out.

The error is shown to be the following line in the views (there is an arrow to it)

Here is the views.py:

```
class OrderSummaryView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):

        try:
            order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
            context = {
                'object': order
            }
            return render(self.request, 'order_summary.html', context)<---------------- Error 
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            messages.warning(self.request, "You do not have an active order")
            return redirect("/")
```

Here is the template:

```
<div class="pull-center">
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'core:update-qty' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" name="action" value="minus" class="btn mr-2"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
        {{ order_item.quantity }}<button type="submit" name="action" value="plus" class="btn ml-2"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
        <input type="hidden" name="item_slug" value="{{ order_item.item.slug }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="order_item" value="{{ order_item.pk }}">
    </form>
</div>                </td>
```

here is the urls:

```
    path('update-qty/<slug>/', update_qty, name='update-qty'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your slug as a template tag argument into your template. Like so:

```html
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'core:update-qty' slug=order_item.item.slug %}">
```